# if I want to increase the session timeout to 60 minutes, is it enough to change in Web.config or also IIS needs to be adjusted?

Tags: visual-studio, session, iis, web-config

if I want to increase the session timeout to 60 minutes, is it enough to change in Web.config or also IIS needs to be adjusted?

We have this Web.config parameter:

```
 <sessionState timeout="15" cookieless="false" mode="InProc" />
```

But what about any settings of IIS?

So can I simply change this Web.config attribute to 60 let's say? Or that's not going to work because IIS has it's own setting which is less than 60, so they user cannot stay logged in for these 60 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if you modify the IIS session timeout value by using IIS management console, it will also modify the web application's web.config file. If you find your setting is not working. I suggest you could check your web.config file in your application root path firstly to make sure the setting has been modified.

I suggest you could also try to test it by using your own IIS management console to make sure it could work well.

Details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Open your IIS management console and locate your web application

2.Select the session state feature and modify the timeout value.

3.Click OK button and open the web site root path web.config file.

Example image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination!